# how do i get my code worked with zerobased correctley?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

i`am trying to Migrating my code to be worked on android so i read here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop

and i understand i have not use `pos` or `delete` with `zerobased` on or i have to turn `zero based off` , i don't feel good about turning of `zero based off`

so i work around my code i changed  `p := Pos(Sep, S);` To  `p := S.IndexOf(Sep, 0,0);` but iam unable to use remove `TStringHelper.Remove` function instead of delete

```
  while (S <> '') and (ParamsCount < 10) do
    begin
      Inc(ParamsCount);
      p := S.IndexOf(Sep, 0,0);
      //p := Pos(Sep, S);
      if p = 0 then
        Params[ParamsCount] := S
      else
      begin
        Params[ParamsCount] := Copy(S, 1, P - 1);
       TStringHelper.Remove(S, 1, P + 4); // here how do i use remove its only have integer parameter how to use Remove instead of Delete 
       //Delete(S, 1, P + 4);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issue here. First of all, the `ZEROBASEDSTRINGS` directive doesn't influence any of this code because you don't use the `[]` operator. However, I recommend that you leave `ZEROBASEDSTRINGS` as `ON` and embrace the new ways.

The string helper use zero based indexing exclusively and it will reduce confusion if you follow suit in your code.

As for the details:

- `Remove` returns a new string, rather than modifying its argument.
- `IndexOf` returns `-1` to indicate no match found.
- Use `Substring` rather than `Copy`. The latter uses old school one based indexing. You should shun all the old `SysUtils` functions and use the helper exclusively.

I'd write the code like this:

```
p := S.IndexOf(Sep);
if p = -1 then
  Params[ParamsCount] := S
else
begin
  Params[ParamsCount] := S.Substring(0, P);
  S := S.Remove(0, P + 3);
end;
```

Your code was a little messy and so there may be some errors in the above. I was trying to decipher the intent from the commented out code. However, the code above demonstrates the style that you should adopt.

Comment: thank you very Much David much that`s helps me a lot

Comment: Sorry, but that, in newer versions of Delphi string is an object?? Wow ;/

Comment: @TheNorth No. It's the same old type. But helpers can be used to extend its method scope. All these methods are supplied by the RTL helper TStringHelper.